# The device connect/disconnect behavior changed in /dev folder after the macOS updated to Ventura 13.0.1

Tags: macos, macos-ventura

I updated the macOS (MacBook Pro, CPU: Apple M1) to `Ventura 13.0.1`recently.
I am working on an IoT device.

Before the update, if I connect my device using a USB cable to the laptop. In the `/dev` folder, I can see my device is listed as a file in the folder, something like `/dev/tty.usbserial-BA5D1LAY`. And I can use this file name as the `Serial line` in `putty` to connect the device's shell. Once I disconnect the device from my laptop, I can see the file is removed from the `/dev` folder.

However, after the macOS is updated to the `Ventura` 13.0.1, the behavior changed. The file name no longer reflects the device connection. Meaning, if I connect/disconnect the IoT device, the files in the folder `/dev` is unchanged. I am no longer able to find out what is `Serial line` for the `putty`. Any idea about how to find out the `Serial line`/device id in the new version of macOS?